# 2022 Ford Maverick XL Rear end damage

Tags: ford, damage, frame, rear

The bar protruding towards the tire - What sort of repair would I need?

[image]

Comment: That piece, which appears to be either a part of the frame or one of the structural parts of the body is clearly damaged.  You would do well to consult a collision repair shop.

Comment: Are you asking for advice on how to do a repair yourself?  Do you have cutting and welding equipment for example?